# display the number of markers in a cluster in Angular google maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am fairly new to AngularJS and currently working with google maps from
http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/

I have gone through the documentation but all i want to do is
show the number markers in a cluster.

and also OnClick of the cluster, a pop-up tooltext shoul be display.
the api does not extensively cover that.
Example of what i want to achieve is here

http://104.131.42.57/frontend/index.html

And below is my current code:

The HTML directive

```
<div ng-controller="MapsController">
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options" bounds="map.bounds">
<ui-gmap-markers doCluster="true" clusterOptions="clusterOptions" models="puMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'">
</ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

The Map Controller, followed the api documentation.

```
controllers.controller('MapsController', function($scope,mapService) {
var locationArray ;
$scope.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: 8.69128,
        longitude: 8.5208073
    },
    zoom: 6,
    bounds: {}
};
$scope.options = {
    scrollwheel: false
};

$scope.clusterOptions = {
    gridSize: 60,
    ignoreHidden: true,
    minimumClusterSize: 5,
    imageExtension: 'png',
    imagePath: 'assets/img/cluster',
    imageSizes: [72] };

var createRandomMarker = function(i, bounds, idKey,point) {
    var ret = {
        latitude: point.g,
        longitude: point.f,
        title: 'm' + i,
        icon: 'assets/img/marker.png',
        options: { title: point.t }
    };
    ret[idKey] = i;
    return ret;
};

$scope.puMarkers = [];
// Get the bounds from the map once it's loaded
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.map.bounds;
}, function(nv, ov) {
    // Only need to regenerate once
    if (!ov.southwest && nv.southwest) {
        var markers = [];

        /* Load Markers from Rest Services*/
        var promise = mapService.getPollingUnits(1);
        promise.success(function(retData,status,headers,config) {
            if (retData.error == false) {
                var i = 1 ;
                locationArray = retData.events;
                locationArray.forEach(function(item){
                    markers.push(createRandomMarker( i, $scope.map.bounds, "id", item ));
                    i++;
                });
            }
        });
        $scope.puMarkers = markers;
    }
}, true);
});
```

Comment: Not sure where you are having an issue. Were your defined markers showing on the map?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figure it out. The number of markers in the cluster was already there only that it was black font't color which hid it because the marker icon was also dark.
Also displaying a popup window when a marker is clicked was already available
in the documentation.